# if statement not executed in javascript [always else]

Tags: javascript

pls can any one help.it always return else..what i want is, when select 1st dropdown,the second dropdown hide and Vice Versa

**html**

```
<form id="myform" onchange="check();" >

<select id="myselecta" >
 <option value="a1">a1</option>
 <option value="a2">a2</option>
</select>

<select id="myselectb" >
    <option value="b1">b1</option>
    <option value="b2">b</option>
</select>
```

**java script**

```
function check() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('myform').value;
        if (dropdown == 'myselecta') {
        document.getElementById('myselectb').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('myselecta').style.display = 'none';
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not have your `onchange` on each select?

Comment: Do *not* use `document.write` here. In any case, a problem is `getElementById('myform').value` does *not* return what you think it does.

Comment: You're getting the value of... the form? In any case, put the event on the selects, and document.write is almost certainly not what you want here.

Comment: you right .getElementById('myform').value not return any thing.i use var dropdown=document.getElementById('myform').getAttribute('id'); it also same. only execute else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to accomplish something like this?

**HTML**

```
<select id="switch" onchange="check();">
 <option value="myselecta">myselecta</option>
 <option value="myselectb">myselectb</option>
</select>

<select id="myselecta">
 <option value="a1">a1</option>
 <option value="a2">a2</option>
</select>

<select id="myselectb">
 <option value="b1">b1</option>
 <option value="b2">b</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function check() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('switch').value;
    if (dropdown === 'myselecta') {
        document.getElementById('myselecta').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('myselectb').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myselecta').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('myselectb').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

### Edit

html

```
<select id="myselecta" onclick="check()">
 <option value="a1">a1</option>
 <option value="a2">a2</option>
</select>

<select id="myselectb" onclick="check()">
 <option value="b1">b1</option>
 <option value="b2">b</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
function check() {
    if (this.id === 'myselecta') {
        document.getElementById('myselectb').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myselecta').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.but it seems enough.but exactly not it.in here some one click myselecta drop-down [ assume:-without clicking switch].. then i want to hide myselectb and viseversa.what i want is  three should be  only one drop drown to  exists when user click on any drop-down.

Comment: @iddamalgoda I've edited my post, is this what you want?

Comment: yes.logic is correct.but ur code also not working.i just run it in JSfiddle ,but it always executed else statement.did u see?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`var dropdown=document.getElementById('myform').value;`

to

```
var dropdown=document.getElementById('myform').getAttribute('id');
```

Comment: try not working.can you edit my code with correct form.

Comment: Scuse me but i did not understand. Try binding onchange event on each select . and then pass id into a function. Es. <select id='s1' onchange="check('s1')" ... > and the same for second select changing id. After that you will check only the parameter inside check function

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, onchange event doesn't capture individual select's onchange events. You should better add an onchange to each individual select element and pass a parameter to the function, like the element's ID to differentiate which element fired the event.